# Using a single event listener instead of many event listeners

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know what is the advantage of using a single event listeners for many components with similar function?

**SO THE FIRST CASE IS**

The HTML file is

```
<div id="button1">
  <h1>button1</h1>
</div>
<div id="button2">
  <h1>button2</h1>
</div>
```

And the script is

```
<script>
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", somefunction);
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", somefunction);
function somefunction() {
}
</script>
```

So here I am attaching two separate listeners to two buttons.

**Now in the second case...**

My HTML is

```
<div id="button1">
  <h1>button1</h1>
</div>
<div id="button2">
  <h1>button2</h1>
</div>
```

And my Script is

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if(target.id=="button1" || target.id=="button2"){
  somefunction();
  }
}
function somefunction() {
}
</script>
```

So I am haveing a common listener for both as well as for the whole window. So what is the difference between both the cases? And which one is good to use? And why?

Comment: Learn about event delegation in general. See also `event.target`

Comment: The second one is better. One listener compared to *n* where n is the growing number of buttons you may add to the page

Comment: @Jonasw 2nd one is better is fine. Can you explain what is the disadvantage of using many listeners? What are the cons?

Comment: @giri dharan the real advantage are dynamically added contents. E. G. instead of redirecting you simply load the main part only instead of the whole page again. With method two you have to traverse this new dom and find all buttons etc. With method two it already works instantly.

Comment: A disadvantage might be slower reacting to an event, which occurs on deep elements structures. It will take some time for an event to bubble up to window. In deeper element structures, it is recommended to add event listeners to the closest common ancestor element instead of window or document.

Comment: @Teemu is there any disadvantage of attaching listener to the window? AS i am trying to generalize the click event functions of various elements of my window as much as possible instead of re-writing the same code.

Comment: Hmm... I thought I've just written about disadvantages of attaching  events to window in my previous comment ..? If the element tree is shallow, there's nothing you should worry about, in that case event delegating is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use classes instead:

```
<div id="button1" class="clickable">
  <h1>button1</h1>
</div>
<div id="button2" class="clickable">
  <h1>button2</h1>
</div>
<span class="clickable">this is a span-button</span>
<p class="clickable">this is a p-button</p>
```

Some jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('.clickable').click(function() {
    // Your code here.
  });
});
```